# Display URL params on page when using react `withRouter` from react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I have a simple component which will be shown when a user resets their password.

To begin with I have set up the route for the component and then created the page (ResetPassword).

I would like to render the url params `key` and `email` to the screen when the route has params added to it after the user has reset their password.

I thought from reading the docs for `withRouter` that i could just access `match`, `params` and then the keys within the url and just render them to the screen. However this is not working.

Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'ramda';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import featureRoute from '../components/Decorators/featureRoute';

type Props = {
  match: {
    params: {
      email: string,
      key: any
    }
  },
  location: {
    pathname: string
  }
};

export const ResetPassword = ({
  match: {
    params: { email, key }
  },
  location: { pathname }
}: Props) => {
  const text = 'view page';

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet title="Page title" titleTemplate="%s" />
      <div className="p-page">
        <div>{text}</div>
        <div>{email}</div>
        <div>{key}</div>
        <div>{pathname}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default compose(
  featureRoute(),
  withRouter
)(ResetPassword);
```

route

```
     {
        component: ResetPassword,
        path: '/password/reset/update',
        exact: true,
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anywhere in your route where the params are defined. I'd expect to see something like

```
path: '/password/reset/update/:email/:key',
```

which may be the cause of the issue.

Additionally, `withRouter` is typically used for class components. Given that you're using a functional component here, you can make use of the [useParams hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams).

The hook is imported with

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and for this case, would be used as follows:

```
export const ResetPassword = () => {
    const { email, key } = useParams();
    const text = 'view page';
```

If you still require the pathname, this can be obtained from the [useLocation hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation).

Comment: Thank you for replying. OK I have been reading the documentation. And I misunderstood what i was meant to do. I need the `query string params` NOT the `params`. If I understand correctly these are different to just `params` right? Your answer helps me so much already though thank you... I need to figure out how to get the `queryparams` now.

Comment: No worries. The query string params are different to those returned by the useParams hook. React Router has an example here on how to get the query string params by way of the useLocation hook here: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters